# Produce an Html RGB value based on the value of the random number produced in C++

Tags: html, c++

I currently have a program that creates me a table full of random numbers (I used "for" loops to do this) and have those numbers change color background depending on their value (example: if the random value is 1 to 2500, the color background of those numbers will be yellow, and 2500 to 5000 will be red). The table was successful, but now I need to produce the RGB values in HTML instead of hardcoding them. (I cant use any kind of logic for HTML..). What kind of strategy should I do to solve this? If anyone can help (hints, examples, or strategies), I would greatly appreciate it :), also, I'm a little new to HTML and slightly intermediate on c++.

```
void makeGap(int gap, std::string & text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < gap; i++)
        text.append(" ");
}

int main() 
{
    ofstream htmltable("MyTask.html", ios::out | ios::trunc);

    array<string, 10> chars = { " Monthly " , " Balance " , " Savings ", " Income ", " Tax Inc. ", " Salary ", " Federal ", " Employee ", " Number ", " Account " };
    int headgap = 3;
    int bodygap = 3;
    int tablegap = 6;
    int rowgap = 9;
    string tabletext("<html>\n");

    makeGap(headgap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "<head>\n";

    makeGap(headgap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "<style>\n";

    makeGap(headgap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "table, th, td { border: 1px solid black;}\n";

    makeGap(headgap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "#p1 {background-color:rgb(255,0,0);}\n"; //red

    makeGap(headgap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "#p2 {background-color:rgb(240,0,0);}\n"; //green

    makeGap(headgap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "#p3 {background-color:rgb(220,0,0);}\n"; //blue

    makeGap(headgap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "#p4 {background-color:rgb(198,0,0);}\n"; //yellow

    makeGap(headgap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "#p5 {background-color:rgb(170,0,0);}\n"; //black

    makeGap(headgap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "#p6 {background-color:rgb(150,0,0);}\n";

    makeGap(headgap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "#p7 {background-color:rgb(120,0,0);}\n";

    makeGap(bodygap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "<H3><BR>Random Table Color Project</H3>\n";

    makeGap(bodygap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "<TR>\n";

    makeGap(bodygap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "<TH TABLE BORDER>\n";

    makeGap(bodygap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "</TH >\n";

    makeGap(bodygap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "</TR>\n";

    makeGap(headgap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "</style>\n";

    makeGap(headgap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "</head>\n";

    makeGap(bodygap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "<body>\n";

    makeGap(tablegap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "<table width = \"1155\">\n";

    makeGap(tablegap + 1, tabletext);
    tabletext += "<thead align=\"center\">\n";

    makeGap(tablegap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "<tr><th></th>";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //Table Names
        tabletext += "<td>";
        tabletext += *(chars.begin() + i);
        tabletext += "</td>";
    }

    tabletext += "</tr>\n";

    makeGap(tablegap + 1, tabletext);

    tabletext += "</thead>";

    makeGap(tablegap + 1, tabletext);

    tabletext += "<tbody align=\"center\">\n";

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); 

    for (int row = 0; row < 38; row++) { //Rows
        makeGap(rowgap, tabletext);
        ostringstream oss;
        int randnumber = rand() % 10000; 
        if (randnumber > 0 && randnumber <= 2500)
        {
            tabletext += "<tr id=\"p1\"><td>"; //red
        }
        else if (randnumber > 2500 && randnumber <= 5000)
        {
            tabletext += "<tr id=\"p3\"><td>"; //blue
        }
        else if (randnumber > 5000 && randnumber <= 7500)
        {
            tabletext += "<tr id=\"p4\"><td>"; //yellow
        }
        else if (randnumber > 7500 && randnumber <= 9000)
        {
            tabletext += "<tr id=\"p2\"><td>"; //green
        }
        else
        {
            tabletext += "<tr id=\"p5\"><td>"; //black
        }
        oss << row;

        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) { //Columns
            oss.str("");
            int randnumber = rand() % 10000; //Random Option
            if (randnumber > 0 && randnumber <= 2500)
            {
                tabletext += "<td id=\"p1\">";
            }
            else if (randnumber > 2500 && randnumber <= 5000)
            {
                tabletext += "<td id=\"p3\">";
            }
            else if (randnumber > 5000 && randnumber <= 7500)
            {
                tabletext += "<td id=\"p4\">";
            }
            else if (randnumber > 7500 && randnumber <= 9000)
            {
                tabletext += "<td id=\"p2\">";
            }
            else
            {
                tabletext += "<td id=\"p5\">";
            }
            oss << randnumber;

            tabletext.append(oss.str());
            tabletext += "</td>";
        }
        tabletext += "</tr>\n";
    }

    makeGap(tablegap + 1, tabletext);
    tabletext += "</tbody>\n";

    makeGap(tablegap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "</table>\n";

    makeGap(bodygap, tabletext);
    tabletext += "</body>\n";

    tabletext += "</html>\n";

    htmltable << tabletext;
    htmltable.close();
    cout << "Writing Table..." << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please modify your code post to only show the "random color generator"

Comment: you already have a strategy there - specifying the `id` of your `td`s based on a `randNumber`. just add an inline style attribute in your `td`.

Comment: Thanks for the help codekaizer, can you explain this a little bit more?, how would i do this?, I'm just grabbing the color from the hard coded background colors in html, (ex: P1 is red). I need color based on the value of the numbers produced in randNumber. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 optional ways (there are definitely more then 2):

**Solution 1**

Create struct vector of colors:

```
struct Color {
    int r, g, b;
};
vector<Color> colors;

void init_colors() {
    colors.push_back({255, 0, 0});
    colors.push_back({0, 255, 0});
}
```

And then rand() the index in the vector that you will use each time.

```
size_t select_idx() {
    return rand() % colors.size();
}
```

**Solution 2**
Random each time RGB parameters:

```
struct Color {
    int r, g, b;
};
Color get_rand_color() {
    return {rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255};
}
```

There are more solutions, but if I would need it, this two solutions would be in my code.

Hope it would help.

Comment: Thanks for the help KorelK!!!, but how would i use output this to html?, it works in c++, i tried using the td's and i'd , but I'm just generating a bunch of random text instead :(, ,,

Comment: Read about tables here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp
In generally:
<table>
<tr><td style="color: red">a</td><td>b</td></tr>
</table>

Comment: I can edit the content and insert an example in your case, if it still doesn't clear.

Comment: I tried your example KorelK, but what i basically need is the color produced in c++  but displayed in html, i basically can't hard code any colors, they have to be produced either randomly or logically based on the random numbers produced on the "2 for loops". I really appreciate you taking time to help me. :)

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is the solution 1 in my main comment. You are looking for logical way, to produce random colors each time, and this is exactcly what it is. If you have a list with 10 colors, and to get new color to use, you can simply random a number between 0 and 9, and return the color that exist in the specific index in the list. Fix me if I'm wrong. BTW, no problem for the help :)